# Distribution of covariance matrix of vectors of lognormal rvs

Tags: probability-distributions, st.statistics, random-matrices

I know that the Wishart distribution is the distribution of the sample covariance matrix of a multivariate normal distribution. I am wondering if the analog distribution for a sample from a multivariate lognormal distribution is evaluted in close form somewhere out there?